# Floating input ports with Generate loop in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I have a code like this:

```
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=0; i<3; i=i+1) begin : label
    dut dut_inst (
    .A (a[i]),
    .B (b[i])
    )
  end
endgenerate
```

both `A` and `B` are inputs to module named `dut`.
I want to make sure that input `A` is not connected when `i==0`. How do I port map this scenario in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to leave out one instance of `dut`, then set the initial value of `i` to 1:

```
for(i=1; i<3; i=i+1) ....
```

If you still want to instantiate dut for 3 times, you could add one extra instance outside the generate loop for `i=0`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'if' statements in the generate blocks as well. Something like the following.

```
genvar i;
generate 
  for (i=0; i<3; i=i+1) begin : label
     if (i == 0)
        dut dut_inst (
           .A (),
           .B (b[i])
        );
     else 
        dut dut_inst (
           .A (a[i]),
           .B (b[i])
        );

   end
 endgenerate
```